# Laravel -Parameter Redirect selecting the same data

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to redirect from one view to the other using parameter. The displayed data will be based on the selected parameter.

Source

Controller

```
    public function revenueReport(Request $request)
{

$revenues = DB::table("vw_revenue_report")
->select(
    "vw_revenue_report.channel",
    DB::raw("SUM(CASE WHEN created_at = NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY THEN amount ELSE 0 END) daily_revenue"),    
    DB::raw("SUM(CASE WHEN created_at >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK THEN amount ELSE 0 END) weekly_revenue"),
    DB::raw("SUM(CASE WHEN created_at >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH THEN amount ELSE 0 END) monthly_revenue"),
    DB::raw("SUM(CASE WHEN created_at >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR THEN amount ELSE 0 END) yearly_revenue"),
    DB::raw("SUM(vw_revenue_report.amount) total_revenue")
)
->groupBy("vw_revenue_report.channel")
->orderByRaw('vw_revenue_report.channel ASC')
    ->get();          

    return view('report.revenueReport');    
}
```

View

```
        @foreach($revenues as $key => $revenue)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ ++$key }}</td>
            <td>{{ $revenue->channel }}</td>               
            <td>{{ $revenue->daily_revenue }}</td>
            <td>{{ $revenue->weekly_revenue }}</td>
            <td>{{ $revenue->monthly_revenue }}</td>
            <td>{{ $revenue->yearly_revenue }}</td>
            <td>{{ $revenue->total_revenue }}</td>
            <td><a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ route('revenueDetail',$revenue->channel) }}">Details</a></td>
        </tr>          
    @endforeach
```

Destination

```
public function revenueDetail(Request $request, $channel = null)
{

    $revenuedetails = DB::table('vw_revenue_report as g')
    ->select(
       DB::raw('DATE(g.created_at) as created_date'),
       'g.msisdn', 
       'g.channel', 
       'g.amount'              
  )
 ->whereRaw('g.channel', $channel ?? null)
 ->orderByRaw('g.created_at DESC') 

->get();
return view('report.revenueDetail');        
}
```

> The parameter 
>   is $channel

The issue I have is that when I clicked on the Details on each row, it redirects me to the same set of data.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views#passing-data-to-views) for Views.

Code example:

```
return view('report.revenueReport', ['revenues' => $revenues]);
```

To use parameter routes, look at [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#required-parameters) documentation.

Code example:

```
Route::get('/report/revenue-detail/{channel}', ['as' => 'revenueDetail', 'uses' => 'ReportController@revenueDetail']);
```

Comment: This is not where the issue is. I've done that and the problem is still there

Comment: Can you post your routes in the original question?

Comment: Route::get('/report/revenue-report', ['as' => 'revenueReport', 'uses' => 'ReportController@revenueReport']);    
    Route::get('/report/revenue-detail', ['as' => 'revenueDetail', 'uses' => 'ReportController@revenueDetail']);

Comment: You're not catching the `channel` for the `revenueDetail` route.

Comment: How? I dont understant